# aac files do not show metadata in explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, metadata, aac

Audio files that appear .aac per the extension will not show information in file explorer in the "Artist", "Title", etc columns when the folder is setup as an "audio" folder.

[image: file explorer with .aac file, no information]

A media tagger application (AudioRanger) does show and save the metadata.  It seems to say the metadata type is ID3v2, but not sure how to confirm that.

Comment: Are they "raw AAC" files, instead of the usual MP4 container files? Raw AAC doesn't have a standard way to store tags (it's why everyone puts it inside MP4).

Comment: @user1686 Not sure. Generally they're named .aac, but many of them I'm able to just rename .mp3 and they still play fine.  In VLC .aac won't show the album art, but once they're renamed it shows up fine; not sure what exactly that means though.

Comment: AAC and MP3 have nothing in common. Lots of audio players or image viewers etc will recognize formats regardless of extension, that doesn't really mean ".mp3" is correct for the file. (And MP3 isn't the container format that was mentioned, MP4 is.) Where did you obtain the files from?